# Can I switch back to Windows 10 after i completely wiped it off my hard drive?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, windows-10

I decided to wipe my hard drive and install a few linux distros such as fedora, kali (I don't even know why I tried kali) and Ubuntu.

I know I wiped my hard drive because when I was switching from fedora to Ubuntu, I accidentally formatted my hard drive instead of my USB drive.

anyway, I've been experiencing problems (don't wanna go into detail, but I think its because I'm still new to linux) and I want to go back to windows 10. how can I do this?

I don't have a windows 10 disk (my laptop doesn't even have a disk drive)

Comment: You will need to create a bootable USB installation disk for Win10 and for that you either need a disk or ISO(disk image) for Win10. For creating USB disk on Ubuntu you can check the link for the software: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Getting Windows 10 is easy: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

If you saved your original Product Key, then you should be all set.
If not, Windows 10 is supposed to read the key from UEFI. Sometimes it works.

If you need to read your original Product Key from UEFI using Ubuntu:

```
sudo strings /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM
```

If you have somehow deleted all record of your original Product Key, then you must purchase a new one from Microsoft.